# How to properly export/import modules for library usage in javascript

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, umd

I want to write a javascript library with two files:

`snabbpixi.js`

```
export function init() {
}
```

`pixiapi.js`

```
export function createElement() {
}
```

I want to use this library like this:

```
import { init } from 'snabbpixi';
import { createElement } from 'snabbpixi/pixiapi';
```

If I don't do anything and set the `package.json` for library as:

```
{
  "main": "src/snabbpixi.js"
}
```

second import doesn't work (`import { createElement } from 'snabbpixi/pixiap'`)

If I compile this library and export as `umd` format using webpack it also doesn't work.

How can I configure my library so I can import like this:

`import { createElement } from 'snabbpixi/pixiap'`

Answer (score 0):

I normally do this sort of thing in TypeScript rather than straight JavaScript, but hopefully this works in basically the same way...

Try creating a new file (typically named `index.js`), with contents like this:

```
export * from './snabbpixi'; // Adjust paths as needed for your particular case.
export * from './snabbpixi/pixiapi';
```

Then make `index.js` your `main`.

The import you would use would then be flattened-out, however, looking more like:

`import { init, createElement } from 'snabbpixi';`

Answer (score -1):

When you are using `import { Something } from 'somewhere'` you are calling on a named export from a given file or directory.

If the two files are in different directories then you can add an index.js file to each directory and then use `export { default as function } from './file'`
To do this you would have to export the default file from `pixiapi` and `snabbpixi`.

If you have both files importing into your `index.js` then you will still want to export them as defaults.  But then you would do the following..

```
import file1 from './file1'
import file2 from './file2'

export default {
file1,
file2,
}
```

This will allow you to use the named imports as well and keep them in the same directory